# xpath to get all elements

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using simplexml to parse xml and I can get single node but not all nodes i want

example

```
    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xml_file); // load the xml file
        $cols = $xmlObject->RESULTSET->ROW->COL;
    foreach ( $cols as $COL) {
        echo $COL->DATA;
    }
```

only gives me the first col of the first row, i tried

```
    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xml_file); // load the xml file
    $cols = $xmlObject->xpath('*//COL');
    foreach ( $cols as $COL) {
        echo $COL->DATA;
    }
```

and got nothing back

any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <RESULTSET FOUND="445">
        <ROW MODID="45" RECORDID="1">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Integrating Ethanol</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>train track and gas pump</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1.jpg</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="29" RECORDID="3">
            <COL>
                <DATA>Keeping in Balance</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>21</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>book cover of Sweet Invisible Body</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
  </FMPXMLRESULT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following XPath expression which ignores the namespace:

```
//*[local-name() = 'COL']
```

This expression selects all nodes with name 'COL' no matter in what namespace the node is in.

Comment: this seems to give me all col items regardless to what row they are in is there some way I can loop through the rows then the col

Answer (score 0):

The right xpath for this would be

```
//COL
```

without the

```
*
```

I think your problem might be that XML namespace, which was causing the problem for me when I ran the XML through this tool that I found using Google:  http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx

Comment: ahh yes that was me playing around but with the wildcard but I took it out and still nada